# Multiple variables in an if statement in Python

Tags: python, validation, max, min

I am trying to have a validation for the user input in a simple min max program. I have more than one inputted integer and I am trying to have one if statement for all the inputted values and if it is not an integer to output an error message. When I try it the way it is set up I can put in integers and non-integers and it will error out in the end saying:

if (number1, number2, number3, number4, number5).isdigit():

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Below is the full code.

```
# Print welcome message
print('Please enter five integers to find the minimum and maximum values.')

# Take 5 numbers from user and convert that to integer and store in variables
validInteger = False
while not validInteger:
    number1 = input('Enter your first integer: ')
    number2 = input('Enter your second integer: ')
    number3 = input('Enter your third integer: ')
    number4 = input('Enter your fourth integer: ')
    number5 = input('Enter your fifth integer: ')
    if (number1, number2, number3, number4, number5).isdigit():
        validInteger = True
else: 
    print('Please enter an integer I.E. 13.')


# Call max function to calculate max value 
max =max(number1,number2,number3,number4,number5)

# Call min function to calculate min value 
min = min(number1,number2,number3,number4,number5)

# Print max number
print('Max value is: ' + str(max))

# Print min number
print('Min value is: ' + str(min))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
if all(x.isdigit() for x in (number1, number2, number3, number4, number5)):
    validInteger = True
```

---

**Why do you get your error?**

`(number1, number2, number3, number4, number5)` forms a tuple and tuple has no `isdigit()` method:

```
>>> type((number1, number2, number3, number4, number5))
<class 'tuple'>
```

[`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) is a method of string.

```
>>> 'abc'.isdigit()
False
>>> '123'.isdigit()
True
```

Comment: Thank you for this that makes much more sense. If I wanted to check each value inputted as they are entered and having an error message display when one is wrong rather than at the end would I be able to use the same process of integer checking?

Comment: @WillKlingenstein, Sure. You can have a similar approach. Please don't forget to mark the helpful answer as accepted by pressing tick on left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `isdigit()` method on each of the input strings in turn:

```
if all(n.isdigit() for n in [number1, number2, number3, number4, number5]):
    validInteger = True
```

The `all()` function examines the results and returns `True` if they are all `True`.